# Gets FileNotFound Exception if managed c# class library dll is not in .exe folder when called form unmanaged code (c++)

Tags: c#, windows, visual-c++, dll, msdn

I have to use the C# class library code in my native code which is written in c++. For this I added one interface written in c++ add the my C# class library project as dependency to it. This works fine till I put the C# dll in .exe folder , but I put this in libs folders (where we keep our dll's), I get file not found exception when tried to call the C# dll function.
Is there any way to keep c# dll in libs folder and make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: When you are calling the dll "LoadLibrary", specify the full path of dll. Or if you don't want to do that, include your libs path to the Windows Path Environment, "PATH"

Comment: I use the C# project as reference project in warpper( project used to interface b/w) I load the warpper with dynamically using LoadLibrary , it gets loaded perfectly but when i tried to call the function of C# form warpper then I get  the issue. I also tried to load the c# dll dynamically before the warpper but that also didn't work.

Comment: I manage to do it by adding a custom AssemblyResolve in my warpper code. Loading the assembly form path. Like currentDomain->AssemblyResolve += gcnew ResolveEventHandler(&Test::MyResolveEventHandler)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to re-add it from the libs folder and it will be fine.  Or if you are naming the DLL in your code itself, then just provide the full path along with the DLL name.  Then when you recompile, the .exe will contain the path you gave it in the source code and will look for the DLL there.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, We are not creating the we are providing the underlying functionality for any application ,currently for application written in java we are using JNI to call the DLL's but now we have to use on c# dll's with c++ dll's. So we used an warpper( project used to interface b/w) (hence not loading c# dll at runtime) I load the warpper with dynamically using LoadLibrary , it gets loaded perfectly but when i tried to call the function of C# form warpper then I get the issue. I also tried to load the c# dll dynamically before the warpper but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN(LoadLibrary)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx),
Remarks section::

> The first directory searched is the directory containing the image
> file used to create the calling process (for more information, see the
> CreateProcess function). Doing this allows private dynamic-link
> library (DLL) files associated with a process to be found without
> adding the process's installed directory to the PATH environment
> variable. If a relative path is specified, the entire relative path is
> appended to every token in the DLL search path list. To load a module
> from a relative path without searching any other path, use
> GetFullPathName to get a nonrelative path and call LoadLibrary with
> the nonrelative path. For more information on the DLL search order,
> see Dynamic-Link Library Search Order.
>
> The search path can be altered
> using the SetDllDirectory function. This solution is recommended
> instead of using SetCurrentDirectory or hard-coding the full path to
> the DLL.
>
> If a path is specified and there is a redirection file for
> the application, the function searches for the module in the
> application's directory. If the module exists in the application's
> directory, LoadLibrary ignores the specified path and loads the module
> from the application's directory. If the module does not exist in the
> application's directory, LoadLibrary loads the module from the
> specified directory. For more information, see Dynamic Link Library
> Redirection.
>
> If you call LoadLibrary with the name of an assembly
> without a path specification and the assembly is listed in the system
> compatible manifest, the call is automatically redirected to the
> side-by-side assembly.

This is all you need to know about path search of a dll. The easy solution, enter the full path in `LoadLibrary` call or set your `PATH` environment variable to contain the alternate path of the dll.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I use the C# project as reference project in warpper( project used to interface b/w) (hence not loading c# dll at runtime) I load the warpper with dynamically using LoadLibrary , it gets loaded perfectly but when i tried to call the function of C# form warpper then I get the issue. I also tried to load the c# dll dynamically before the warpper but that also didn't work.

Comment: How you are calling the dll function ? You do the `GetProcAddress` ?

Comment: For warpper functions I am using GetProcAddress , But for C# dll I am calling it directly (as c# project is used as reference project ).

Comment: In that case, I think, you have to check the reference path in your project manifest file. You might be trying to reference the dll from some other path.

Comment: I am not getting any option for setting reference path in VC++ project, Also I don't know the location of dll's at compile time, I get to know it at runtime by getting the module path.

Comment: Youa re getting the error in your C++ project or C# project ? Post some relative code. You can use dynamic memory to load the dynamically known dll path.

Comment: Thanks Abhijeet for your help. I manage to do it by adding a custom  AssemblyResolve in my warpper code. Loading the assembly form path. Like currentDomain->AssemblyResolve += gcnew ResolveEventHandler(&Test::MyResolveEventHandler);